# Android BitmapDrawable setTileModeXY REPEAT not working

Tags: android, bitmapdrawable

I am having an issue with BitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY.

I have searched about this issue extensively on Google, StackOverflow and other websites. Most people with a problem seem to be using XML, while people using code who had problems were all on older versions (before ICS). However, I am using Android 4.2.2, and have minSdkVersion set to 17, and targetSdkVersion set to 19.

I am using the following code:

```
public void applyTiledBitmap(ImageView imageView, Bitmap bitmap, Resources resources)
{
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
    drawable.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

The ImageView fills the entire screen. The image is small and centered using imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER).

According to what I have read in multiple threads, this should result in a tiled image. But it does not. I have been playing around with this for hours and nothing I try makes any difference.

Any ideas? Or am I missing something ridiculously obvious?

Comment: use imageView.setDrawable(drawable); but in this case there is no need of using ImageView,  simple View will do the trick

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I can display images in something like a RelativeLayout using a BitmapDrawable and ignore ImageView completely? Is there some advantages/disadvantage to using ImageView and a Bitmap instead of BitmapDrawable?

Comment: sure you can do that,  i prefer Drawables as they are higher abstraction level and Bitmaps are static, dead "Still life"

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use:

ImageView.setBackground(BitmapDrawable)

This allows using tiling, while also still being able to use ImageView.setScaleType(), which cannot be done using a normal ViewGroup.